# find if a number set has intersection with another set

Tags: java, algorithm, numbers

**background:**

the service port number in firewall access-list has different format like:

single number: 22,443

range:10000-65535

I am working around some analysis to the firewall, need to find if a specified port reside in the access-list port numbers

**for example:**

the acl service port is String[] servicePorts = {"20-22","443","8080-8088","10000-65535"}

need to find if {"5672","15672-15674"} in the servicePorts

**Plan1:**

convert the servicePort into a Set, leave the rest works to Set Api

**Plan2:**

convert the ports into an unified format, each element has a "start-end" number like:

targetPorts = {"20-22","443-443","8080-8088","10000-65535"}

myPorts = {"5672-5672","15672-15674"}

then need to loop myPorts, check each elements against targetPorts elements with the comparation of start/end number.

Plan1 is more simple but is really heavy coz the ports set contains large elements.

I've considered there could have some binary operating method, but has no way out.

Any other plan to deal with the number intersection problem?

or which plan do you prefer.

Comment: Is it Java or Python?

Comment: whatever, it's ok,  I prefer Java, thanks.

Comment: If you prefer Java, then please remove the Python tag.

Comment: *"Plan1 is more simple but is really heavy coz the ports set contains large elements."* Indeed. Plan 1 is not very good. Plan 2 on the other hand, is great. Go ahead with plan 2!

Comment: I'd go for approach no. 2: use a sorted list of ranges where a single port would have the same lower and upper boundary, then select those ranges that could potentially intersect with each range in "myPorts" and check those (no need to check _all_).

Comment: Python is good!

Comment: Just use if and compare the end and start ports. There are only a few cases to handle:  range 1 equal range 2, range 1 before range 2, range 1 after range 2, end of range 1 in range 2 (== start of range 2 in range 1), start of range 1 in range 2 (== end of range 2 in range 1). Any particular difficulties encoding that as a sequence of if statements?

Comment: The code will be easier to write if you encapsulate it in functions. First, write a function that converts the mixed list `{"5672","15672-15674"}` into a list of ranges `{"5672-5672","15672-15674"}`. Then, write a function that compares two ranges, and returns True or False to say whether they intersect or not.  Then, write a function that compares two lists of ranges, using the function that compares single ranges.

Comment: Or the straightforward, non-optimized version: `start1 in range2 || end1 in range 2 ||  start2 in range1 || end2 in range1`. `in` as a function could be as simple as `value >= start && value <= end`

Comment: Yes , I agree, Plan2 is not that much complicate, but ... not better options?

Comment: Plan 2 is very good. Implement plan 2. When plan 2 works, you can try to implement other options for fun if you want. Focus on one option first. Plan 2 is good.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do a quick analysis of the 3 approaches that have been mentioned so far.

For the analysis we're using the following variables:

- number of acl ranges: `n`
- number of ports in the acl: `a` (where `a >= n`)
- number of service ranges: `m`
- number of ports in the service: `s` (where `s >= m`)

**Approach 1: Build set of individual ports**

- Development complexity: simple - add single values, iterate over ranges and either put values into the set or check for them
- memory complexity: depends on the number of ports (up to 65k entries) - `O(a + s)`
- time complexity: assuming you're using a properly sized `HashSet` you'd get O(1) complexity for inserts and lookups, so `O(a + s)` complexity

Note: if you build the acl set once complexity gets down to `O(s)` for each service.

**Approach 2: Build sorted list/tree of acl ranges and check unsorted list of service ranges**

- Development complexity: simple/medium - convert single values to ranges, look for potential overlaps, check for actual overlaps
- memory complexity: depends on the number of ranges but presumably considerably lower than number of ports - `O(n + m)`
- time complexity: `O((m + n) * log(n))`

  - build acl list: `O(n * log(n))`
  - iterate over service port list: `O(m)`
  - lookup and check for overlap in each service port range: `O(m * log(n))`  (could be more for freak situations but those aren't likely)

Note: if you build the acl list once and can reuse it time complexity gets down to `O(m * log(n))` for each service.

**Approach 3: Build single labelled list and count starts/ends** (approach suggested by גלעד ברקן)

- Development complexity: simple/medium - build labelled list, keep track of counts for both labels
- memory complexity: depends on the number of ranges but presumably considerably lower than number of ports - `O(n + m)`
- time complexity: `O((n + m) * log(n + m))`

  - iterate over n and m ranges for both lists: `O(n + m)`
  - sort the combined list: `O((n + m) * log(n + m))`
  - iterate over the list once more to count: `O(n + m)`

Note: you could build a sorted list for the acl once, copy it for each service and use insert sort etc. to add the service ranges. That would bring down time complexity to `O(m * log(n + m))` (`O(m)` for the iteration over `m` ranges and `O(log(n + m))` for the lookup of the insertion point of each range).

**Conclusion**

Given this analysis approach 2 would be preferable due to the lower time complexity (`O(n + m) * log(n))` as compared to `O((n + m)*log(n + m))`) and similar memory and development complexity (albeit the latter is more subjective).

For very small ranges approach 1 could be more feasible but that can turn very fast and approach 2 has the better general properties (i.e. for an unknown number of ranges with an unknown size).

Comment: you have my respect!

Comment: we should give more concern to time complexity, coz the numbers of acls in a firewall is huge as many as tens of thousands, and within a single acl the service group  always has several dozens lines.

Comment: Good point about reuse.

Answer (score 0):

Plan 3, insert each start and end as a labeled tuple in a *single* sorted list

```
(t, start, 20), (t, end, 22), (t, start, 443), (t, end, 443), (m, start, 5672), (m, end, 5672), (t, start, 8080), (t, end, 8088), (t, start, 10000), (m, start, 15672)...
```

Traverse from small to large and keep a running count for each label by incrementing by 1 when encountering a start for that label, and decrementing by 1 when encountering an end for that label. An intersection is found if one count is greater than 0 when the other also becomes.

Comment: Be careful not to return a false positive if the first list or ranges intersects itself without intersecting the second list.

Comment: @Stef could you provide a small example I didn't address?